# PySpark - how to update Dataframe by using join?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe a:

```
id,value
1,11
2,22
3,33
```

And another dataframe b:

```
id,value
1,123
3,345
```

I want to update dataframe a with all matching values from b (based on column 'id').

Final dataframe 'c' would be:

```
id,value
1,123
2,22
3,345
```

How to achieve that using datafame joins (or other approach)?

Tried:

```
a.join(b, a.id == b.id, "inner").drop(a.value)
```

Gives (not desired output):

```
+---+---+-----+
| id| id|value|
+---+---+-----+
|  1|  1|  123|
|  3|  3|  345|
+---+---+-----+
```

Thanks.

Comment: it will cast you but it will get you the result .
scala> dfd.join(df.select("id"),Seq("id"),"inner").union(df.join(dfd,Seq("id"),"left_anti")).orderBy("id").show

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is an update functionality. But this should work:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df1.join(df2, df1.id == df2.id, "left_outer") \
   .select(df1.id, df2.id, F.when(df2.value.isNull(), df1.value).otherwise(df2.value).alias("value")))
```

Comment: This is close by looking at the logic but getting error `raise TypeError("Column is not iterable")`

Comment: Replaced `column()` with `select()`